# Error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 2 is out of range

Tags: java, sql-server, web, jdbc

```
I have a function to update the user's information as follows:

public void updateAccount(String username, String name, String address, String aboutMe, String 
id) {
    String sql = "update Account set username = '?', \n"
            + "                [Full_Name] = '?',\n"
            + "                [Address] = '?',\n"
            + "                [about_me] = '?'\n"
            + "                where id = ?";
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, username);
        ps.setString(2, name);
        ps.setString(3, address);
        ps.setString(4, aboutMe);
        ps.setString(5, id);
        ps.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AccountDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

and this code is giving me an error like this: 

Severe: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 2 is out of range.
```

at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setterGetParam(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:933)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setValue(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:948)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setString(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1578)
at dao.AccountDao.updateAccount(AccountDao.java:117)
at controller.UserProfileController.doPost(UserProfileController.java:91)

**I don't understand why it gives me the error "The index 2 is out of range" and is there any
way to fix it?**

Comment: By the way… [Text blocks](https://openjdk.org/jeps/378) in Java 15+.

Comment: You only have **one** parameter, the rest are **string literals** with a question mark in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't enclose `?` parameter markers in quotes. These are typed by the appropriate setter:

```
String sql = "update Account set username = ?, \n"
        + "                [Full_Name] = ?,\n"
        + "                [Address] = ?,\n"
        + "                [about_me] = ?\n"
        + "                where id = ?";
```

Comment: Your answer is really helpful, but I have 1 more problem after fixing it. That is, I still cannot update the user's information with the following error:

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'username', table 'FERA_ONL_LEARNING.dbo.Account'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

I'm sure I changed their values and it can't be NULL. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I would expect `ps.setString(1, username);` to set the parameter value accordingly. If you see a non-NULL value when debugging, you could run a server-side trace of the RPC call to capture the actual values sent.